# if checkbox checked and textarea is empty, else

Tags: jquery

I checked through the questions and answers and I'm nearly there. Just need a bit of help to complete.

If a user check a checkbox and leaves the textarea empty inser message. If checkbox is checked and textare is not empty, show the answer.

I only want the action to run on each row as its check box is checked. Currently it affects all rows. Thanks for any help

Table

```
<table id="activity">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">1</th>
            <th scope="col">2</th>
            <th scope="col">3</th>
            <th scope="col">4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="answer" /></td>
            <td>concrete</td>
            <td><textarea id="response1" name="response1" title="response1" rows="3" class="form-control"></textarea></td>
            <td class="answer_block"><span>Answer 1</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="answer" /></td>
            <td>concrete</td>
            <td><textarea id="response2" name="response2" title="response2" rows="3" class="form-control"></textarea></td>
            <td class="answer_block"><span>Answer 2</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="answer" /></td>
            <td>concrete</td>
            <td><textarea id="response3" name="response3" title="response3" rows="3" class="form-control"></textarea></td>
            <td class="answer_block"><span>Answer 3</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><button type="submit" name="check" id="button-check">Check</button> <button type="reset" name="reset" value="reset" id="button-reset">Reset</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>

</table>
```

script

```
$('button#button-check').on('click' , function() {
    $('.answer').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked') && !$.trim($(".form-control").val()).length ){
           $('.form-control').val('Input can not be left blank');
           $(this).parent().siblings().children('span').hide();
       } else {
        $(this).parent().siblings().children('span').show();
        } 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may it help

```
$('button#button-check').on('click' , function() {
$('.answer').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).closest('tr').find('textarea').val() == ""){
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.form-control').attr('placeholder','Input can not be left blank');
       $(this).closest('tr').find('.answer_block span').hide();
   } else if($(this).is(':checked')){
       $(this).closest('tr').find('.answer_block span').show();
    } 
});
```

});

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/y8jx51wh/1/)

Comment: Thanks Mohamed-Yousef, however, when any of the check-boxes are checked and the text-area is empty that rows answer x is blank but the other rows answer shows. 

This is what I am trying to achieve for each row / check-box / text-area

1. if a check-box is checked and the corresponding text-area is empty show message "Input can not be left blank", don't show answer.
2. if check-box is checked and text-area is not empty show answer
3. Each row is independent.

Thanks :-)